# How do I make my code check that the user has input a alphabetical character? [Java]

Tags: java

**Update**: the code works now. Thanks for help guys.

---

This is part of the code I'm having trouble with

```
if ((amount < 0) || (Character.isLetter(amount)))
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here's a piece of my code:

```
try
      {
       if ( theStock.exists( pn ) )        // Button CHECK
       {
           thePicture.clear();                       
           if ( actionIs.equals( Name.ADD ) ) {
               try 
               {
                   amount = Integer.parseInt(theInputPQ.getText());      // Checks that
                   if ((amount < 0) || (Character.isLetter(amount))) {   // number has been
                       theOutput.setText("Please enter sufficient No."); // input
                    }
                    else {
                        theStock.addStock(pn, amount);
                        Product pr = theStock.getDetails( pn ); // Add to
                        theAction.setText(                      // stock of
                        pr.getDescription() + " : " +           // item
                        theMoney.format(pr.getPrice()) + 
                        " (" + pr.getQuantity() + ")" );
                    }                       
                }

                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    theOutput.setText("Please enter sufficient No.");

                    Product pr = theStock.getDetails( pn );              
                    theAction.setText(                    
                    pr.getDescription() + " : " +       
                    theMoney.format(pr.getPrice()) +    
                    " (" + pr.getQuantity() + ")" );

                    if ( actionIs.equals( Name.ADD ) ) {
                    } 
                }
            } else {                                   // F
                theAction.setText(                    //  Inform Unknown
                "Unknown product number " + pn );    //  product number
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having exactly?

Comment: What type hast theInputPQ? Maybe we would understand your Problem if wie know exactly where the value is coming from.

Comment: @MikeJack - could you reduce this to a short (very short) version that can be run in the "main" of a java application? Hardcode the input that doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: Replacing the question with thanks makes it completely useless for other people who find it at a later time - If you want to thank people for the help, do so in a comment.

Comment: I rolledback (and sanitized) the question.

Comment: You could use a scanner as well.
( http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html )

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if an `int` is a  letter or not:

```
 Character.isLetter(amount)
```

If that int is for instance `65` that method would return true, because what in ascii code the number `65` represents the letter `a`

This is probably the source of your problems.

You may safely remove that validation, because, if after the call to `Integer.parseInt`  you may be sure that `amount` **is** a number ( otherwise it will go to the `catch( NumberFormatException )` section below as you may already have noticed.

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason when I remove the "Character.isLetter(amount)".

Answer (score 0):

Is `amount` a `int` variable? if it is, how it can be a letter (`Character`)? if not `int`, then how it can be compared using `< 0`? It can be or character or integer, not both above.

Comment: It looks like he's trying to validate whether or not amount is a number in first place. It make ( some ) sense to ask if `amount` is a letter, it is just he doesn't quite know how ( which I why he came here isn't? )

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that you are already checking if amount is an int by the:

```
Integer.parseInt(theInputPQ.getText());
```

and the try-catch block. don't need to do the

```
Character.isLetter(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `amount < 0` check isn't doing anything useful, unless you are checking for integer values less than 0.  `Integer.parseInt()` returns the integer that it read, as a string.  It throws a `NumberFormatException` if its argument does not contain a parseable integer.

I would call a different method if your goal is just to figure out if the button's text has letters in it.  Also, I'm not sure why you're calling `isLetter()` on the text of a String.  Here's an example I saw that goes character-by-character:

```
String str = theInputPQ.getText(); // I assume this is a String
for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
           System.out.println("It's a digit");
        if(Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)))
           System.out.println("It's a letter");
}
```

In the interest of good coding practices, if you add this code then it should be a separate private method.

Sources: [Java API for Integer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), [Dream in Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=22076)